# AndroidアプリでJSONICを使用した、デコード、エンコード処理を実行するとExceptionエラーになってしまいます

Tags: android, android-studio, json

AndroidStudioにてAndroidアプリを制作しております。 
JSONICを使用して下記の処理を実行すると、JSON.encode(hm);でExceptionエラーになり、printStackTraceでjsonicのライブラリが見つからない旨のメッセージが表示されます。

Exceptionエラーが発生せず、JSONICを使用したエンコード、デコードを実行する方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけないでしょうか。

```
try{
    HashMap<String,Object> hm = new HashMap<>();

    hm.put("001","いちご");
    hm.put("002","にかん");
    hm.put("003","みかん");

    String json = JSON.encode(hm);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

e.printStackTrace();での出力結果

> W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while
>   initializing Lnet/arnx/jsonic/OptionalConverter;  W/System.err:
>   java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle
>   'net.arnx.jsonic.Messages_ja_JP', key ''  W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.missingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:238)

ライブラリのファイル配置

> app\src
>   app\libs
>   app\libs\jsonic-1.3.10-sources.jar 
>   app\libs\jsonic-1.3.10.jar

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/jsonic-1.3.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsonic-1.3.10-sources.jar')
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/72979

Answer (score 1):

Android Studioでブランクプロジェクトを作成し、jsonic-1.3.10を使用してみましたが、特に問題なく使用できました。

但しその際に、2つほど気になる点がありました。

1. build.gradle：`dependencies`の`compile files`は不要です
   `compile fileTree`でlibs配下のjarを指定しているので、改めて`libs/*.jar`を個別に指定する必要はないと思います。
2. `jsonic-1.3.10.jar`と`jsonic-1.3.10-sources.jar`の2つを含める必要はありません
   両方含めた場合、こちらの環境ではエラーが発生しました。

   > ```
   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
   > com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK net/arnx/jsonic/Messages.properties
   > ```

---

また質問文にあるエラーについてですが、
`Can't find resource for bundle 'net.arnx.jsonic.Messages_ja_JP', key ''`
このエラーはアプリのクラスパスに`net/arnx/jsonic/Messages_ja.properties`もしくは`net/arnx/jsonic/Messages.properties`が含まれていないことが原因です。

---

**・2つのjar含めてもエラーが発生していない

・`Can't find resource for bundle 'net.arnx.jsonic.Messages_ja_JP', key ''`のエラーが発生している**

上記２点から考えると、ビルドしたアプリに`jsonic-1.3.10.jar`が正しく含まれていないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。返答が遅くなり大変申し訳ありません。

ご指摘いただいた通り、ライブラリを重複して読み込んでしまっていたのが原因でした。そのため、下記のビルドエラーが出てしまい、
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK net/arnx/jsonic/Messages.properties

exclude 'net/arnx/jsonic/Messages.properties'とexclude 'net/arnx/jsonic/Messages_ja.properties'をgradleに追加し、読み込まないようにしてしまっていました。
アプリで呼び出そうとすると、参照先がないため、エラーでアプリが落ちてしまっていたようです。

こちらの単純ミスも原因の一つにあり、お恥ずかしい限りですが解決にご協力いただきありがとうございました。